# session not created exception for chrome in Protractor

Tags: selenium-webdriver, typescript, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I get below error when try to run Protractor test against chrome.

My conf.ts

```
import {Config} from 'protractor'

export let config: Config = {
    framework: 'jasmine',
    // capabilities: { browserName: 'chrome'},
    multiCapabilities: [
        // {browserName: 'firefox'},
        {
            browserName: 'chrome',
            chromeOptions: {
                args: ['--start-maximized']
            },

        }],

    seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
    seleniumPort: null,
    seleniumArgs: [],
    specs: [
        './Protractor/Login/*.spec.js',
```

Error:

```
Protractor conf.js
[17:19:07] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
[17:19:07] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[17:19:09] E/launcher - session not created exception
from unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"8800.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.59)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.22.397933 (1cab651507b88dec79b2b2a22d1943c01833cc1b),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 1.07 seconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'MAL000009416062', ip: '192.168.1.4', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_73'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
[17:19:09] E/launcher - SessionNotCreatedError: session not created exception
from unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"8800.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.59)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.22.397933 (1cab651507b88dec79b2b2a22d1943c01833cc1b),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 1.07 seconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'MAL000009416062', ip: '192.168.1.4', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_73'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    at WebDriverError (C:\Users\392811\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:27:5)
    at SessionNotCreatedError (C:\Users\392811\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:308:5)
```

**conf.ts**

```
multiCapabilities: [

        {
            browserName: 'chrome',
            chromeOptions: {
                args: ['--start-maximized']
            },

        }],
```

Most of the discussion on the web is around version. I am currently using up-to-date versions

Any clue please?

Cheers

Comment: manually download chrome driver version 2.24 and replace it with existing chromdriver.exe file.

Comment: @SudharsanSelvaraj I have `chromedriver_2.24.exe` under this path `node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can change the version of chromedriver downloaded by webdriver-manager by altering Protractor's config.json file...

1. Edit Protractor's config file: node_modules/protractor/config.json
2. Change the chrome driver version to whatever you need. eg. "chromedriver": "2.24".
3. Run webdriver-manager update.

from the error you posted, protractor is not using the latest chrome driver version.In stack trace it is displaying chrome driver version as `2.21`.

Comment: I am using `multiCapabilities: ` and updated the question with `conf.ts ` section. Still doesn't update with `webdriver-manager update ` command.

Comment: edit the conf.json file present in ` node_modules/protractor/config.json`. not your project's `conf.js`

Comment: I added that to `tsconfig.json ` in the mentioned location. Then ` webdriver-manager update ` results produced below. `I/update - chromedriver: file exists C:\Users\392811\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_2.22win32.zip
[20:29:17] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_2.22win32.zip
[20:29:17] I/update - chromedriver: v2.22 up to date`

Comment: I realized that I have updated `webdriver-manager ` at the global location. That's why I am getting wrong version there. After updated the correct place it was good.

Comment: upgrading chromedriver worked for webdriverio tests also. I was getting the same error.

Comment: If it is possible, upgrading to the latest version of protractor can also help. In my case there was no config.json in the protractor folder and updating the tconfig.json in the webdriver had no impact

Answer (score 7):

I don't have enough rep yet to leave a comment under Sudharsan's answer but the location of the config file he is telling you to modify is actually at

```
node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/config.json
```

It's not the protractor tsconfig but the webdriver-manager `config.json` that you want to modify.

That being said, I've run into this problem before and taken a different approach to solving it. The solution that Sudharsan provided would work if you only needed to install it once. We have our builds running in TFS which cleans out the build agents working directory and pulls in a fresh repo on each build. Changing the webdriver config would not work in this situation because we `npm install` all the things before each build. In this case it would always revert back to the older version of chromedriver.

What I did instead was added chromedriver to my devDependencies in the `package.json` and then I delete the version of chromedriver that webdriver-manager installs and move the updated version of chromedriver into the correct location with a gulp task. So in the package.json I have this listed under devDependencies:

```
"chromedriver": "~2.24.1"
```

and then I have a gulp task that deletes and moves the files like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var del = require('del');

var chromeDriverFilesToMove = [
    './node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver/**'
];

var chromeDriverFilesToDelete = [
    './node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver*.exe',
    './node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver*.zip'
];

gulp.task('delete-chromedriver', function() {
    return del(chromeDriverFilesToDelete);
});

gulp.task('move-chromedriver', function() {
    gulp.src(chromeDriverFilesToMove)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/'));
});

gulp.task('chromedriver-update', ['delete-chromedriver', 'move-chromedriver']);
```

And because protractor will still be looking for the older version of chromedriver that was installed when you ran `webdriver-manager update` you have to tell it where to look for the chromedriver.exe so add this to your protractor conf.js and it should start working.

```
chromeDriver: "../node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver.exe",
```

It's kind of silly that we have to go through all this trouble to get it to work but chromedriver 2.22 doesn't seem to work with Chrome 53+. At least not in my experience.

TL;DR

If you only have to install it once use Sudharsan's solution (given you modify the correct config), it's easier. If you are in my situation and will have to install protractor continuously try my solution. It has worked well for me and I haven't run into this error since.

Answer (score 4):

I just needed to:

```
npm update -g protractor
webdriver-manager update
```

And it worked again.

Answer (score 1):

Protractor has a new release (4.0.10) that will use the new release of webdriver-manager (10.2.6), which in turn will update to the new Chromedriver when calling webdriver-manager update. All you need to do is update Protractor in your package.json file.

```
"protractor": "^4.0.9" to "protractor": "^4.0.10"
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This worked for me, I am already on latest protractor and chromedriver version. And was getting this error - E/launcher - session not created: Chrome version must be between 70 and 73. I am using- "protractor": "^5.4.1", and [14:44:36] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_2.46.zip
[14:44:39] I/update - geckodriver: unzipping geckodriver-v0.24.0.zip. Above solution worked for me. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

1. Just run the following command:
2. **Projectdirectory:/>webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=ChromeVersion**
3. *Replace this with "ChromeVersion" Google Chrome Browser Version.Find chrome version by navigating to "Help>>About Google chrome>>For Example: Version **76.0.3809.100** (Official Build) (64-bit)".*

I hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

For me, updating chromedriver and `protractor-conf.js` fixed the issue.

1. Download latest chromedriver that suitable to your OS (change the minor version if needed) from here: http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.24/
2. Unzip to `/usr/local/bin/chromedriver` folder.
3. In `protractor-conf.js` (should be in app root) add a line with `config.chromeDriver = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver';`

Answer (score 0):

There is a package.json file under your webdriver-manager folder of users directory - change its webdriver-version to latest one. It should work

"name": "webdriver-manager",
"version": "12.1.8",