# Protractor / Selenium Webdriver : Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context'

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I use protractor to test Angular2 app. It was working fine and I think I didn't change nothing in conf but now it ends up with this:

```
...

super(opt_error);
    ^
SessionNotCreatedError: session not created exception
from unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"4012.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.71)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459

...
```

I work on a Mac OSX 10.11.4, Chrome 54.0.2840.71.

Any suggestion? Thanks

--- EDIT 26/10

Since it depends on each one settings it looks like theres no absolute answer to this. The main idea is to update protractor/ chromedriver / webdriver-manager accordingly.

Saying that i now face another problem : every basic test i do, including ( for instance ) a browser.get() is failing with :

```
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL
```

I don't know if it's an isolated case and if it fits here (I use jasmine2 as framework) so I start another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40238648/protractor-jasmine-error-timeout-async-callback-was-not-invoked-within-ti)

Comment: Try re-installing protractor. even i was facing the same issue today.

Comment: Or install protractor with below version `npm install protractor@4.0.9  -g`

Comment: thanks. I did it. no success...

Comment: This also helped me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40100960/session-not-created-exception-for-chrome-in-protractor/40101565#40101565

Comment: thanks. Actually i had mismatch version between global webdriver and local protractor. i clear it up by uninstalling global and update protractor and webdriver in local.

Comment: I haven't changed anything in my setup and I'm experiencing the same thing this morning... only on chrome.  Firefox and others run fine, must be a driver issue.

Comment: I manually downloaded chromedriver 2.24 from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.24/ and add it to node_modules/protractor/selenium. Then change node_modules/protractor/config.json to "chromedriver": "2.24". it solves the issue but then another problem comes in : Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL

Comment: this might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38918486/protractor-getting-runtime-executioncontextcreated-has-invalid-context-erro

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protractor - Getting "Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context" error when i run Protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38918486/protractor-getting-runtime-executioncontextcreated-has-invalid-context-erro)

Answer (score 7):

I installed [ChromeDriver v2.24](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) and stored it in: /usr/local/Cellar/chromedriver/2.24/bin and it fixed the error for me.

Comment: That worked for me too. The important part is to put the chromedriver on your path as described here: http://watir.github.io/docs/chrome/
Just that the version linked to in the watir documentation is confusing. Using http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.25/ should work.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by others, looks like it is a problem with the chromedriver installed in the system with the new version of chrome. For mac, I updated the chromedriver using 'chromedriver-update' and this fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and solver it by forcing chromedriver 2.24 to install by manually removing webdriver-manager

delete the folder `rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/webdriver-manager/`

reinstall webdriver
`npm install -g webdriver-manager`

Answer (score 0):

I updated the `selenium-standalone` to the latest version `5.8.0` (from `5.1.0`). It will install the newer version of chrome webdriver(2.25), instead of install chrome driver2.21. This solved the issue on my end.(no connection, session exception)

Answer (score 0):

If **even after updating** the webdriver to *2.25*, the error is still occurring **and if** you are using the **terminal app** this should help :

I managed to fix the issue by unchecking “*Set locale environment variables on startup*” checkbox in advanced terminal app settings.
Or try to launch your test with this prefix :

```
LC_NUMERIC=”en_US.UTF-8″ npm test
```