# Selenium: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context':

Tags: python, macos, selenium, automated-tests, chrome-web-driver

I looked the similar question here [Protractor / Selenium Webdriver : Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40235380/protractor-selenium-webdriver-runtime-executioncontextcreated-has-invalid-c) and here [BUG-1473](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1473), but I cannot get the answer hence I decided to give it here.
I installed latest chrome_driver v2.9, but still getting `Runtime.executionContextCreated` error.
Here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.google.com/xhtml')
```

And thrown exception on the python shell:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/humoyun/Documents/virtual_env_fold/flasky/fl_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 248, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/Users/humoyun/Documents/virtual_env_fold/flasky/fl_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/humoyun/Documents/virtual_env_fold/flasky/fl_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"2061.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.95)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248307,platform=Mac OS X 10.11.3 x86_64)
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I've found dozens of threads with the same problems running a rock-bottom basic example and none of them have a solution.

Answer (score 11):

i had similar issue , i used chrome driver version 2.25 for mac and it worked.

Comment: also for windows

Answer (score 5):

I had similar problem.
After I downgrade my chrome driver version from 2.9 to 2.27, it works.
Maybe you could try to downgrade it.

Comment: I got a similar error in a C# application and I can confirm that downgrading to v2.27 worked for me

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass your chromedriver path to the Chrome() constructor

```
path = '/path/to/chromedriver'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
```

please let me know if it is fixed. Also it is advised to try with latest chromedriver and raise issue in case if any.

Comment: Actually I added chromeriver's path to the system path, if I had not included it I would get different error, but as you can see the exception was thrown after __driver.get('http://www.google.com/xhtml')__ not after __driver = webdriver.Chrome()__ and showing that it is found (Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.95) (Driver info: __chromedriver=2.9.248307__, platform=Mac OS X 10.11.3 x86_64) and the version is the latest.

Comment: did you try with latest stable release of chromedriver?

Comment: yes of course, you can see it from output, **Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248307**

Answer (score 3):

As of Mar 2018, Latest release of chrome webdriver is 2.37. 
Refer [Chromium ChromeDriver downloads](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)  page where you can get the latest stable releases . What you might be using is an unstable dev release. Documentation should always be the first step of debugging and not the stack overflow

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline

Comment: @baduker: linked as per your suggestion

Comment: This is helpful, thank you. For many, Stack Overflow + search engine of choice is much faster than searching through documentation for programs they are not familiar with. Your answer has helped the masses avoid digging through the docs : ) 

Make sure you match chromedriver to your chrome version, as the above linked Downloads page suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Update the chromedriver version and after that browser launched successfully.