# Selenium WebDriver / NetBeans 8.1 / JDK1.8.0 Exception ChromeDriver Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context' "

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, netbeans, selenium-chromedriver

I'm a newbie with Selenium WebDriver. I found some sample code, and adapted it a little bit to get my own test program. I'm having trouble with it! Here's the program:

```
package test;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class SeleniumTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       try {
           System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
           WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
           driver.get("http://www.oddsportal.com/");
           driver.manage().window().maximize();
           String str = driver.getCurrentUrl();
           System.out.println("The current URL is " + str);
       }
       catch (Exception ex) { 
           System.out.println("Encountered exception in SeleniumTester.main() :");
           System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
       }
   }
}
```

It compiles fine, and starts running, first outputting some diagnostics:

```
"Starting ChromeDriver (v2.9.248315) on port 11716
October 25, 2017 6:11:22 IP. 
org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS"
```

But then, at the line "driver.get(...);" an exception occurs :

```
"Encountered exception in SeleniumTester.main() :
unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"8164.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T16:15:40.131Z'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-47EFBCO', ip: '192.168.43.83', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\Ilkka\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir12200_17489}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=61.0.3163.100, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=XP, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 31a4a5806225e18533805ed0fbbca392"
```

Something about invalid context. What does it mean? How to fix it? Should I perhaps use a different constructor to create the ChromeDriver? Ideas, anyone?

Comment: Most likely the issue is because of an older version of chromedriver. Download a newer version of chromedriver and try giving its path.

Comment: A quick search pointed to questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41832859/selenium-runtime-executioncontextcreated-has-invalid-context

Comment: I downloaded version 2.33 of chromedriver.exe from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.33/. And now my test program works! In other words, it opens the oddsportal.com front page and displays it in a maximized Chrome window. Thanks a lot for your advice, Atul!

Comment: Glad to help. Will add it as answer. Please accept it. And then maybe vote for the question to be closed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context':](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41832859/selenium-runtime-executioncontextcreated-has-invalid-context)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the issue is because of an older version of chromedriver. Download a newer version of chromedriver and try giving its path.

The browser version and driver version compatibility issues could cause this issue. The [chromedriver page](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) mentions the driver compatibility for browser version. For example, as of now, the page lists:

Latest Release: ChromeDriver 2.33
Supports Chrome v60-62