# Selenium invalid context

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm beginner in selenium webdriver. I'm trying to implement a basic java program to run selenium webdriver. But I can't success because, it's give me 
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException.

**chrome version: 69.0.3497.100
chromedriver version: 2.43 
selenium-server version: 3.14.0
selenium-java version: 3.14.0
And also add selenium-server-stanalone-3.13.0 jars.**

Getting the error from these code.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/chromedriver");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://google.com");
```

The error is:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context'

What can I do? How fixed this? If you can, please share with me.

Comment: Check this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41832859/selenium-runtime-executioncontextcreated-has-invalid-context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got my mistake. I have added the latest chromedriver. But all the times, we don't need the latest version. The most important thing is, first have to check "chromedriver" version, then to check installed browser's version. It may not support the latest version, then have to try lower versions. In my case, chromedriver 2.42 has worked.

Comment: By downgrading _chromedriver_ you are pulling a rug over the actual issue which you must avoid at all possible cost.