# SessionNotCreatedError: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, gulp, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

We have AngularJS protractor tests. The process is to set up and run these steps in order:

```
$ npm install
$ webdriver-manager update --ie32 --ignore_ssl
$ gulp
```

The problem I'm having is this setup works for everyone else on my team but 100% of the time I receive this error:

```
[11:42:33] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[11:42:36] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://10.222.189.129:55574/wd/hub

/path/to/repo/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:27
    super(opt_error);
    ^
SessionNotCreatedError: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time: '2017-08-29T12:54:15.039Z'
System info: host: 'xxxx', ip: 'xxxx', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.6', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
   at WebDriverError (/path/to/repo/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:27:5)
   at SessionNotCreatedError (/path/to/repo/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:214:5)
   at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/path/to/repo/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:505:15)
   at parseHttpResponse (/path/to/repo/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
   at doSend.then.response (/path/to/repo/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:440:13)
   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
   at Function.createSession (/path/to/repo/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:777:24)
   at Function.createSession (/path/to/repo/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:709:29)
```

The problem is something to do with my setup but I'm at a loss, so throwing a Hail Mary on SO hoping anyone has any advice.

Please let me know if you need any additional info. Thank you in advance, I've wasted a lot of time trying to get this to work!

Comment: Chromedriver requires an actual Chrome browser installed as well. Try upgrading your chrome browser. Also, can you manually start a Chrome session on the selenium hub - i.e. run `webdriver-manager start` then launch the hub portal at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub (or where ever you have configured it to be), click Create Session -> Chrome.

Answer (score 18):

This can be fixed by updating to the latest version of both chromedriver and chrome.

If you are using webdriver-manager, run

```
webdriver-manager update --chromedriver
```

Then download Chrome from https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/ and replace your old chrome with the latest version.

You will also need to *Ctrl-C* in the terminal where webdriver is running and run

```
webdriver-manager start
```

Or kill and restart the Selenium daemon process to capture the latest chromedriver.  A system restart might be helpful.

Also worth trying:

```
npm update -g protractor
webdriver-manager update
```

Also see [session not created exception for chrome in Protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40100960/session-not-created-exception-for-chrome-in-protractor/40121176) for more details on how to modify the version of Chromedriver in protractor's config

Lastly, make sure that your protractor.conf.js has

```
   commonCapabilities: {
     'browserName': 'chrome',
   },
```

or else you should be using

```
--browser chrome
```

flag on your protractor command

Comment: Had the same problem, restarting the PC and updating have helped.

Answer (score 3):

- Run webdriver-manager start
- Open any browser manually, than navigate to 'localhost:4444/wd/hub' , click Create Session -> Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the below in your config you can download the latest chromedriver.exe and run it directly with the below code. Only geckoDriver and chromeDriver work with directConnect.

```
directConnect: true,
chromeDriver: 'path_to_chromedriver',
geckoDriver: 'path_to_geckodriver.exe',
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. Just install or update the protractor. If you still installed the protractor also Do the following steps, run the following in cmd prompt or PowerShell

```
npm install protractor -g 

npm install webdriver-manager -g
```

If you got the error as running in the background, check the running processor and close all the running processor and try.

After the above steps run the following

```
webdriver-manager update
webdriver-manager start
```