# Is there any way to start a selenium server from the command prompt with out internet

Tags: protractor

i would like to run the selenium server from the command prompt with out the internet connection. Every time when i run below command

webdriver-manager start will always needs internet connection to start the server because this commands is checking for new binaries .

But i would like to run the selenium server with the binaries which are already downloaded to my system with out checking for new binaries.

When i search for above question i found a below solution.

webdriver-manager start --versions.standalone version number

Even though i am using above command and try to run the selenium server by specifying the version number still it is depends on internet connection.

Can any one help me how to start the selenium server with out internet . I dont want checking process while starting the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, `webdriver-manager start` execute a Java CLI after query latest binary, so you can just execute the Java CLI directly if you have download the binary to avoid access internet to query latest binary.

```
set Webdriver_Basedir=C:\Tools\npm-global\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium

java
-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=%Webdriver_Basedir%\chromedriver_2.35.exe -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=%Webdriver_Basedir%\geckodriver-v0.19.1.exe -jar %Webdriver_Basedir%\selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1.jar -port 4444
```

Comment: can you please share protractor configuration file , where and how to include above line of code in it ,

Comment: selenium server is running and the protractor test script is also running successfully . @yong thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

1.Download Selenium Remote Control from http://seleniumhq.org/download.
2.Extract the ZIP file.
3.Start a Command Prompt or a console window and navigate to where the ZIP file was extracted.
3.Run the command java –jar selenium-server-standalone.jar

Please try this the above

Comment: By using above command the selenium server is running , but after running the server and i run protractor protractor.conf.js --suite testfile then it is displaying SessionNotCreatedError: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService error message and protractor script is not running

Comment: Please go through this link https://www.guru99.com/protractor-testing.html you will get idea

Comment: In that links i found the information that need to specify "selenium address:http://localhost:4444/wd/hub" in "configuration" file and run the selenium server from the command prompt, i followed these steps , still i am getting above error message

Comment: I think, this can be fixed by updating to the latest version of both chromedriver and chrome and also refer to the link given below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46433957/sessionnotcreatederror-unable-to-create-new-service-chromedriverservice