# How to set chromeDriver location in Protractor project

Tags: selenium, protractor

In my Protractor project I get below error when execute `npm test` command

```
21:55:20] E/runner - Unable to start a WebDriver session.
[21:55:20] E/launcher - Error: SessionNotCreatedError: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: '00000FJ26VN2', ip: '172.30.161.17', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

I tried below solution and didn't work for me.

[Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46433957/sessionnotcreatederror-unable-to-create-new-service-chromedriverservice)

[This couldn't do due to my machine restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55201226/session-not-created-this-version-of-chromedriver-only-supports-chrome-version-7)

Other question I have is even after replacing the correct `chromedriver` in the below location when I start the server it still shows the wrong one. (i.e. `chromedriver_75.0.3770.8.exe`, But I replace that with `chromedriver_74.0.3729.6.exe` which is my current browser version.

File Location: `protractor-cucumber-typescript\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium`

logs when start the server

```
λ npm run webdriver-start

> protractor-typescript-cucumber@4.0.0 webdriver-start c:\Repository\GitExt\Protractor\protractor-cucumber-typescript
> webdriver-manager start

[22:08:04] I/start - java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=c:\Repository\GitExt\Protractor\protractor-cucumber-typescript\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_75.0.3770.8.exe -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=c:\Repository\GitExt\Protractor\protractor-cucumber-typescript\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\geckodriver-v0.24.0.exe -jar c:\Repository\GitExt\Protractor\protractor-cucumber-typescript\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -port 4444
[22:08:04] I/start - seleniumProcess.pid: 1380
22:08:04.708 INFO [GridLauncherV3.parse] - Selenium server version: 3.141.59, revision: e82be7d358
22:08:04.825 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$3] - Launching a standalone Selenium Server on port 4444
2019-06-13 22:08:04.883:INFO::main: Logging initialized @446ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
22:08:05.145 INFO [WebDriverServlet.<init>] - Initialising WebDriverServlet
22:08:08.881 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 4444
```

So as a resolution Can I pointing to the **chromedriver** specifically? What is the relationship between `selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar` and the `chromedriver`? Is there a way to find the compatible `chromedriver` version for this `jar`

In my case I don't have access to update or downgrade my machine chrome browser version. So how it's possible to change the web driver version to align with chrome browser version.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/cc501f71bc1f995a83c1041e1aa489ea0f105679/lib/config.ts#L76 This is what you want.

Comment: @tehbeardedone In my case session doesn't even start. The question is even I replaced with different version of `chromedriver` why it is still looking for `c:\Repository\GitExt\Protractor\protractor-cucumber-typescript\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_75.0.3770.8.exe -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=c:\Repository\GitExt\Protractor\protractor-cucumber-typescript\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\geckodriver-v0.24.0.exe`?

Comment: Under the `webdriver-mamnger` folder in `config.json` I can see `"chromedriver": "2.27",` line under `webdriverVersions` list. Is that the reason I see the chrome version that mentioned in the above comment, each time when I start the server in spite of different `chromedriver.exe` placed in the folder.

Comment: After deleting `chromedriver_75.0.3770.8.exe` from folder `c:\Repository\GitExt\Protractor\protractor-cucumber-typescript\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\` it worked. The question is because now no `chromedriver.exe` in the folder then where does the application picks up `chromedriver.exe`. Actually that's the initial question I had anyway. When I start the server it shows `[11:28:16] I/start - java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=c:\AGLRepository\GitExt\Protractor\protractor-cucumber-typescript\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\geckodriv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue here and managed to have resolution.

Problem : Even though I placed the matching `chromedriver.exe` in path (`c:\Repository\GitExt\Protractor\protractor-cucumber-typescript\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium`) it's still looking for the original version which is coming from`webdriver-update` command.

So what I did was

1. Removed `chromedriver` from the above path.
2. Add the preferred one in some folder location and set that in env. variables. So if the driver is missing in the project folder it always goes to set path in the env. variables which the right one.

Despite of above solution I just wondering how I can change the driver version when run `webdriver-update` command?

Comment: I found this command to set the required chrome browser version `node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 77.0.3865.75 `