# Protractor: "session not created: Chrome version must be between 71 and 75"

Tags: angular, google-chrome, protractor, angular-e2e

I'm trying to run Angular Protractor e2e tests and getting this error:

```
session not created: Chrome version must be between 71 and 75
```

Comment: [session-not-created-exception-for-chrome-in-protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40100960/session-not-created-exception-for-chrome-in-protractor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this problem is to upgrade the Chrome version to the latest and webdriver-manager to the latest.

- Upgrade Chrome version to latest:

Go to Chrome --> Help --> About Google Chrome and update to the latest version

**Method 1: Upgrade Webdriver Manager**

- Upgrade webdriver-manager to latest:

Go to your project and upgrade webdriver-manager to the latest with the below command:

```
npm update protractor -g
node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --gecko=false --versions.chrome <version_number>
```

**Method 2: Uninstall Node, Protractor, and install again and upgrade Webdriver-manager**
If webdriver-manager is not upgraded to latest then uninstall the node, protractor and then install by following the below steps

- Uninstall Node, npm, protractor

Go to the terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/{lib/node{,/.npm,_modules},bin,share/man}/{npm*,node*,man1/node*}
```

To completely uninstall node + npm, do the following:

1. go to /usr/local/lib and delete any node and node_modules
2. go to /usr/local/include and delete any node and node_modules directory
3. If you installed with brew install node, then run brew uninstall node in
   your terminal.
4. Check your Home directory for any local or lib or
   include folders, and delete any node or node_modules from there
5. Go to /usr/local/bin and delete any node executable

You may also need to do:

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/local/bin/node /opt/local/include/node /opt/local/lib/node_modules
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node.1 /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d

rm -rf /Users/[homedir]/.npm  (eg:- rm -rf /Users/Sarada/.npm)
rm -rf /Users/[homedir]/.nvm
```

You can verify whether it uninstalled or not by running the following commands (you will get the response as *blank)

```
which node
which npm
which protractor
```

- Install Node & npm

Download the latest node.js from https://nodejs.org/en/download/ website and unzip and install.

goto terminal and check the node and npm version installed

```
node --version
npm -v
```

- Install protractor

run the following command in terminal to install protractor

```
sudo npm install -g protractor

sudo webdriver-manager update
```

- Upgrade the chromedriver version in the project

Go to the project and remove the 'node_modules' folder and run the following commands to install the latest version of the chrome driver.

```
npm install

webdriver-manager update
```